# how to call stored function with mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I start to learn Mybatis and I searched around howto deal with stored function.
I'd like to know howto call a stored function with mybatis. 
I can use stored procedures like described here http://loianegroner.com/2011/03/ibatis-mybatis-working-with-stored-procedures/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

your mapper file should have something like this

```
<update id="myMappedStatement" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
  {#{returnedVal,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT} = call myFunc(
       #{myParam1, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR,
       mode=IN},#{myParam2, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR,
       mode=IN},#{myParam3, javaType=String, jdbcType=VARCHAR,
       mode=IN})}   
</update>
```

the calling function should look something like this:

```
public String myFunction(Map myParams)
{
  //assuming the dao has an Object sqlSessionFactory of type SqlSessionFactory
  SqlSession session = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();
  try
  {
    session.update("myMappedStatement",myParams);
    //now myParams contains an entry with key "returnedVal"
    return (String)myParams.get("returnedVal");   
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {

  }finally {
    session.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Posting a comment here since this is the first result that comes up when looking up "Call stored function mybatis".

The word `call` in the query is *case sensitive*. It must be entirely lower case! If you attempt to use 'CALL' in all caps, you will get an error!

This drove me nuts for hours, because I didn't realize this is the *one keyword* that is case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

You might express the return value as an OUT parameter.

`{ CALL #{retval, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER} = getResult(#{inval, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER})}`

At least that's what I found here:
http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/How-to-map-function-call-td3457305.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using annotations, like this:

```
@Select(value = "select function(#{param1}, #{param2}) as returnedValueAlias")
public ReturnedType getFunctionValue(
                    @Param("param1") Param1Type param1,
                    @Param("param2") Param2Type param2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this at the moment :

```
<resultMap id="resultBalance" type="Balance">
    <result property="balance" column="BALANCE"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getBalance" parameterType="Registration" resultMap="resultBalance">
    select MB_CHECK_BALANCE( #{account} , #{msisdn} ) as BALANCE from dual
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on ibatis, so it should work on mybatis as well:

```
<parameterMap id="obtenerModoConsultaParams" class="java.util.HashMap" > 
    <parameter property="modoConsulta" jdbcType="INTEGER" javaType="java.lang.Integer"  mode="OUT"/>
</parameterMap> 

<procedure id="modoConsulta.element" parameterMap="obtenerModoConsultaParams" >
    {? = call proceso_consulta_ruc.modo_operacion_consulta_ruc ()} 
</procedure>
```

And in JAVA

```
public Integer loadModoConsulta() throws Exception {
    Integer result = null;
    HashUtil<String, Object> param = new HashUtil<String, Object>();
    getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("modoConsulta.element", param);
    result = param.getInt("modoConsulta");
    return result;
}
```

That works for me.