# iBatis 3, JAVA, ORACLE and Functions

Tags: java, oracle, ibatis

I have a FUNCTION in ORACLE that take a LONG and returns a STRING.

```
FUNCTION "GEN_NEXT_COD_NRE" (AN_ID_MEDIC IN NUMBER)
RETURN VARCHAR2
```

As I read, in iBatis 3 there is no  tags and then there is no IN or OUT map to be set.

So in my DAO, I have something like this:

```
public String createNextNre(MedicContract contract);
```

and my map is:

```
<select id="createNextNre" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType="string" parameterType="MedicContract">
{? = call GEN_NEXT_COD_NRE(#{idMedic})}
</select>
```

Unfortunally, this way doens't work. This is is the ERROR:

```
SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [how to call stored function with mybatis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9901608/how-to-call-stored-function-with-mybatis) and messing around, I got something similar to work by simply doing

```
<select id="getTestFunction"
    statementType="CALLABLE"
    resultType="String">
    select TEST_PKG.test_function() from dual
</select>
```

This works because in Oracle functions are callable in select statements. Alternately the call syntax works if you have your parameter class set up to hold the OUT param:

```
<select id="getTestFunction2"
    statementType="CALLABLE"
    parameterType="com.somecom.test.model.TestBean">
    {
    #{value,mode=OUT,jdbcType=VARCHAR} = call SYS.UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(TEST_PKG.test_function())
    }
</select>
```

With TestBean.java being:

```
public class TestBean {
    String value;

    public String getValue() { return value;}
    public void setValue(String value) { this.value = value;}
}
```

Note that the OUT param is set on your parameter class, not a result, so you'll need to do something about that in your DAO method:

```
public TestBean getTestFunction2() {
    TestBean param = new TestBean();
    getSqlSession().selectOne("getTestFunction2",param);
    return param;
}
```

It's been a while since you posted so you probably figured it out, but I found this looking for the answer myself so figured I should respond.